# Set bash variables from XML tags

Tags: variable, xml, xmlstarlet

I have the following xml file

`<root>
<deviceID>IO238470374109730497</devicdeID>
<KeyValuePairs>
    <KeyValuePair>
      <BASE-URL>site.com</BASE-URL>
      <Key>329482</Key>
      <Value>23094</Value>
    </KeyValuePair>
    <KeyValuePair>
     <BASE-URL>anothersite.com</BASE-URL>
     <Key>36657</Key>
     <Value>1233</Value>
   </KeyValuePair>
    <KeyValuePair>
     <BASE-URL>yetanothsite.com</BASE-URL>
     <Key>3345</Key>
     <Value>65087</Value>
   </KeyValuePair>
</KeyValuePairs>
</root>`

I would like to extract the values of all `<BASE-URL>,<Key>,<Value>` and set them to variables in a bash script.

executing this command will only print the values

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//KeyValuePair' -v 'concat(BASE-URL," ", Key, " ", Value, " ")' -nl file.xml`

How can I set these values to variables?

I want to extract the values from the xml and send them to variables like this `<BASE-URL>` to `$base_url` , `<Key>` to `$key` and `<Value>` to `$value`.

Comment: What variable names do you expect? (`site.com` is not a valid variable name)

Comment: I want to extract the values from the xml and send them to varialbles like this `<BASE-URL>` to `$base-url`  , `<Key>` to `$key` and `<Value>` to `$value`

Comment: `base-url` is also an invalid variable name...

Comment: can you suggest valid names please.. anything that do the trick.

Comment: [A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Comment: You should add your clarification to the question. Instead of `base-url` you could use `base_url` or `baseurl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values never contain spaces you can do something like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//KeyValuePair' -v 'concat(BASE-URL," ", Key, " ", Value, " ")' -nl file.xml | while read base_url key value
do
    echo "base_url=$base_url key=$key value=$value"
done
```

Comment: It works.. you saved my day.. thank you very much!